# Problem in solving equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

While solving algebric I stuck on solving these pair of equations simulatneously: 
\begin{align}
(x^2-y^2)(x-y)= 16xy\\
(x^4-y^4)(x^2-y^2)=640x^2y^2
\end{align}
I have tried many substitution like $y=mx$ or $x+y=u$ and $x-y=v$ but nothing seems to work. Is there any other way out to solve these equations simultaneously?

Comment: square the first equation and divide by the second. Subject to some conditions you should end up with $(x-3y)(3x-y)=0$

Comment: @lozenges You should give this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Divide equation $2$ by equation $1$:

$$\frac{x^4-y^4}{x-y} = 40xy$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)}{x-y} = 40xy$$
$$\Rightarrow (x^2+y^2)(x+y)= 40xy$$
$$\Rightarrow x^3+x^2y+y^2x+y^3= 40xy \tag{3}$$

And now expand equation $1$:
$$x^3-x^2y-y^2x+y^3 = 16xy $$
$$\Rightarrow x^3+y^3 = 28xy \tag{4}$$

therefore:

$$x^2y+y^2x = 12xy$$
$$xy(x+y) = 12xy$$
$$x+y = 12 \tag{5}$$

Substituting this into the first equation gives a quadratic, which results in $x=3,9$, and $y=9,3$; so the solutions are $(3,9)$ and $(9,3)$.

We also have the case where $x-y=0$ or $x=y$. This gives the solution $(0,0)$ as well.

Comment: I have got $x+y=12$ so this means tha $y=12-x$
Putting $y=12-x$ in first equation 
\begin{align}
(x^2-(12-x)^2)(x-(12-x))=16x(12-x)\\\
(x^2-144-x^2+24x)(2x-12)=16(12x-x^2)\\\
(12x-72)(x-6)=8(12x-x^2)\\\
12x^2-72x-72x+432=96x-8x^2\\\
20x^2-240x+432=0
\end{align}
Now this equation is not giving me the desired result. Where did I went wrong?

Comment: In the third line, you are missing a factor of $2$ on the LHS.

Comment: actually I divided both LHS and RHs by factor 2. Earlier it was
\begin{align}
(24x-144)(2x-12)=16(12x-x^2)
\end{align}
After cancelling factor 2 both the side we get
\begin{align}
(12x-72)(x-6)=8(12x-x^2)
\end{align}

Comment: On the LHS you have divided by $4$ ($2 \times 2)$ . On the RHS you have only divided by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The resultants of the two polynomials (when written as $f(x,y)=0$) with respect to both variables are, up to a constant, $x^{12}(x-3)(x-9)$ and $y^{12}(y-3)(y-9)$. This leaves us with only nine cases to check, and we find that there are three distinct solutions: $(x,y)=(0,0),(3,9),(9,3)$.